# Defining and Calling a Function within a Python Class

Tags: python

I'm creating a class and I'm hoping to call a user-defined function within a method for that class. I'd also like to define the function within the class definition. However, when I call the class, I get the error message `name *whatever function* is not defined`.

For instance, something like this:

```
class ExampleClass():

    def __init__(self, number):
        self.number = number

    def plus_2_times_4(x):
        return(4*(x + 2))

    def arithmetic(self):
        return(plus_2_times_4(self.number))
```

But when I call:

```
instance = ExampleClass(number = 4)
instance.arithmetic()
```

I get the error message.

So basically I want to define the function in one step (`def plus_2_times_4`) and use the function when defining a method in another step (d`ef arithmetic...`). Is this possible?

Thanks so much in advance!

Comment: use  `return(ExampleClass.plus_2_times_4(self.number))`

Comment: `return` is a statement, not a function. While using parentheses and no space *works*, it is not really the norm. Use `return 4 * (x + 2)` instead, so a space after `return`, then the expression.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Define and call `plus_2_times_4` with `self`, namely:

```
class ExampleClass():

    def __init__(self, number):
        self.number = number

    def plus_2_times_4(self,x):
        return(4*(x + 2))

    def arithmetic(self):
        return(self.plus_2_times_4(self.number))
```

This will work.

Comment: also if `number` is an instance variable, if you make `plus_2_times_4` an instance method you don't need to pass an argument in. Just do `def plus_2_times_4(self): return(4*(self.number + 2))`

Answer (score 5):

Call the method using `ExampleClass.plus_2_times_4`:

```
class ExampleClass():

    def __init__(self, number):
        self.number = number

    def plus_2_times_4(x):
        return(4*(x + 2))

    def arithmetic(self):
        return(ExampleClass.plus_2_times_4(self.number))
```

Alternatively, use the `@staticmethod` decorator and call the method using the normal method calling syntax:

```
class ExampleClass():

    def __init__(self, number):
        self.number = number

    @staticmethod
    def plus_2_times_4(x):
        return(4*(x + 2))

    def arithmetic(self):
        return(self.plus_2_times_4(self.number))
```

The `@staticmethod` decorator ensures that `self` will never be implicitly passed in, like it normally is for methods.

Comment: @joaquin Whoops, you're right. I added a bit of clarification.

Comment: The staticmethod option should be preferable over accessing the method via the class name. The next option is to just add `self` and leave it a method. And suggest to just move the function *out of the class*.

Answer (score 2):

Look at your `plus_2_times_4` and `arithmetic` definitions. There’s no way for Python to tell that you wanted one of them to be a local function and the other one to be a method. They’re both defined exactly the same way.

And really, they’re both. In Python, anything you put in a `class` statement body is local while that class definition is happening, and it becomes a class attribute later.

---

If you want to be able to call the function as `plus_2_times_4` later, you don’t want this. You just want to declare a global function, outside the class definition. And that really does seem like what you want here. The function doesn’t have any inherent connection to the class; it just takes a number and does stuff to that number without any thought of anything about your class.

Or, if you don’t want to “pollute the global namespace”, you can just define it as a local function within `arithmetic`. Then `arithmetic` can just call it—and nobody else can.

---

If, on the other hand, you want it to be a method, you have to make it usable as a method. A normal instance method has to take `self` as an extra first parameter, even if it’s not going to do anything with `self`. (Although not doing anything with `self` is usually a sign that you wanted a global function, not a method, it’s not illegal or anything.) And it has to be called on an instance, like `self.plus_2_times_4(…)`.

You could declare it as a static method by adding the `@staticmethod` decorator. Then you don’t need to add the useless `self` parameter. But you still need to call it on an instance or on the class, because it’s still an attribute of the class, not a global name. (You could also use `@classmethod` if you have some idea of wanting subclasses to override it, but that doesn’t seem likely here.)

---

What if you really want to just capture the function value so you can call it without going through the class? Well, you could make it the default value of a parameter, like this:

```
def arithmetic(self, *, _func=plus_2_times_4):
    return func(self.value)
```

Default values are captured at function definition time—that is, while the class is still being defined—so the function is still local there and can be captured there. But if this seems weird and ugly, there’s a good reason for that—this is not something you usually want to do. To a reader, the function still looks like an incorrect method rather than a disposable function needed by `arithmetic`. It even ends up as a member of the class, but it can’t be called normally. This is all pretty misleading. In the rare cases you need this, you probably want to give it a `_private` name, and `del` it once you’ve used it.